# Passing parameters to an ant build building an eclipse plugin

Tags: plugins, ant, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to build an eclipse plugin from console which works fine.
Now I want to add a parameter to the ant script. I looked it up and and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776135/how-to-pass-parameters-for-a-ant-script-which-is-invoked-via-shell-script) that I can pass an arbitary parameter like this:

```
 -D{paramName} {paramValue}
```

Also [the official documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_feature_generating_antcommandline.htm) says I can put it after the `-application` parameter. It states:

*Note that the parameters appearing after the application are the parameters that are passed to Ant.*

This is my build script which runs fine if I do not specify the additional custom `-DeclipseLocation` parameter.

```
java
-jar C:\Eclipse_3.7.2_WIN32\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -DeclipseLocation "D:\Program Files\Eclipse_3.7.2_WIN32" -buildfile  D:\build.xml
```

When running I get the an error message that says

```
Unknown Argument: -DeclipseLocation
Unknown Target: "D:\Program Files\Eclipse_3.7.2_WIN32
No known target specified
```

So what am I doing wrong. How can I pass custom parameters to my ant build here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is

```
-D{paramName}={paramValue}
```

You **must** have an '=' between the name and the value

Comment: Thanks again Greg, you are very helpfull as always! I should clean my glasses I guess...